# How do I use the update command in git add -i?

Tags: git, git-add

In interactive, the update command just lists the commands again:

```
$ git add -i
           staged     unstaged path
  1:        +0/-3      nothing .bowerrc
  2:        +4/-1      nothing .meteor/packages

*** Commands ***
  1: status   2: update   3: revert   4: add untracked
  5: patch    6: diff     7: quit     8: help
What now> u
*** Commands ***
  1: status   2: update   3: revert   4: add untracked
  5: patch    6: diff     7: quit     8: help
What now> 2
*** Commands ***
  1: status   2: update   3: revert   4: add untracked
  5: patch    6: diff     7: quit     8: help
What now> update
*** Commands ***
  1: status   2: update   3: revert   4: add untracked
  5: patch    6: diff     7: quit     8: help
What now>
```

git version `2.2.1`

According to

http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Interactive-Staging

I should expect:

```
           staged     unstaged path
  1:    unchanged        +0/-1 TODO
  2:    unchanged        +1/-1 index.html
  3:    unchanged        +5/-1 lib/simplegit.rb
Update>>
```

Comment: Have you tried `patch`?

Comment: Git says that your changes are already staged. `unstaged: nothing`. So `update` can't really do anything for you, can it?

Comment: personally, I think it's not good to ask question using self-defined alias, may causing confusion. Just using `git add -i` instead of `ga -i`.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing an important "state" that your repo must be in for the `update` command to do anything. From the doc examples, you can see:

```
$ git add -i
           staged     unstaged path
  1:    unchanged        +0/-1 TODO
  2:    unchanged        +1/-1 index.html
  3:    unchanged        +5/-1 lib/simplegit.rb

*** Commands ***
  1: status     2: update      3: revert     4: add untracked
  5: patch      6: diff        7: quit       8: help
What now>
```

However your state is:

```
$ ga -i
           staged     unstaged path
  1:        +0/-3      nothing .bowerrc
  2:        +4/-1      nothing .meteor/packages
```

The difference is in your staged/unstaged columns. The `update` command is purposed for staging new changes. Since you have nothing unstaged, the `update` command completes with no prompt.

Answer (score 0):

All changes had already been staged. Once I unstaged with `git reset`, it worked correctly.